# Calling Shell - explorer search in VBA - Workaround

Tags: vba, shell, excel, search, explorer

I have a code in VBA that will call explorer with a given search parameter and will find and list files with a given name in explorer on a specific location.

code:

```
RetVal = Shell( _
"c:\Windows\explorer.exe ""search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results&crumb=System.Generic.String%3A~%3D" _
& filename & "%20kind%3A%3Dfolder&crumb=location:" _
& location, vbNormalFocus)
```

It works nicely while I was using it on English windows.

Is there any way to improve this code so it would work on other language platforms or at least a workaround for it to make it work on German Windows?

Edit:

To clarify what I need to happen:

There are hyperlinks in a workbook with different names (ex. "banana"), when a user opens a hyperlink named "banana", the script calls the shell, opens an explorer window and lists all the files (these files are not excel files like `.xls`) containing the word "banana" in an already defined folder.

Since other language Windows explorers use different search commands, it only works on English Windows.

A search on German Windows would look like something this:

```
search-ms:displayname=Suchergebnisse%20in%20"SYS%20(C%3A)"&crumb=System.Generic.String%3A & filename & &crumb=location: & location
```

If you want to try it yourselves note that the location should also look something like this: `C%3A%5C` for `C:\` in order to make it work.

Edit2:

So I have figured out what the problem was. The part `%20kind%3A%3Dfolder` is different in German Windows, so as I got rid of that, it started working on both platforms.

Here is the working version:

```
RetVal = Shell("c:\Windows\explorer.exe ""search-ms:displayname=backup%20for:%20" & _
backup & "&crumb=System.Generic.String%3A~%3D" & backup & _
"%20&crumb=location:" & location, vbNormalFocus)
```

I am still looking for a way to get the same results without using Shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd Answer demonstrating FSO

```
Sub GetFiles()

Dim FSO as Object 'Late binding <- Prefered method
'or As New FileSystemObject  for Early Binding 
'but don't forget to add a reference to Scripting Runtime!
Dim oFile as Object
Dim oFolder as Object
Dim sFileSpec as String
Dim r As Integer

r = 1
sFileSpec = "banana"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\path\to\Predefined\Folder\") 
'Or use the folder picker method already used

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If Instr(1, oFile.Name, sFileSpec, vbTextCompare) Then
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Cells(r, 1) = "File Name:"
            .Cells(r, 3) = "File Size:"
            .Cells(r, 5) = "Date:"
            .Cells(r, 2) = oFile.Name
            .Cells(r, 4) = oFile.Size
            .Cells(r, 5) = oFile.DateLastModified
        End With
        r = r + 1
    End If
Next oFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! The only problem is that you should change the last `Else` to `Next oFile` and it works like a dream

Answer (score 1):

@Jeanno nailed one method of getting all the files that matched "banana". This just tweaks his/her code to get all Word documents (but you can see that it will find.txt, .html, or *.* too). Another method would be to use a FileSystemObject (FSO) to do exactly this same thing. You could also use wscript (Windows Script Host) to get the information even though it would over complicate things. There are many ways to skin this cat. :)

```
    Dim myFolder As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long, tempLimit As Long
    Dim r As Integer

    r = 1
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Title = "Select Folder Containing .doc Files"
    myFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            myFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    myFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.doc*")
    Do While myFile <> ""
        'Do what you need to do with the found files
        Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value = myFile

        'Call Dir again without arguments to loop through all files that matched our criteria
        myFile = Dir
        r = r + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: I am starting to understand the method used here, but what I need is to list these files in an explorer window. How do I do that?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way of opening Explorer without using Shell. (Well, there might be, but it would be very involved and very complex). If these *must* be displayed in explorer, you're kinda stuck with Shell. What are users doing in/with the files displayed in the Explorer window? If they are simply opening them, it would be easy enough to add a userform that displays the returned files and they can open them from there. Or, if they are copying them, you can script that too.

Comment: The users need to see the file(s) displayed with file names, file size and date modified, choose the one that suits them best and access it as easy as possible. If there are no other ways than I am stuck with explorers overcomplicated method. It took me a while to make it even work so my hands are tied if I want to modify something.

Comment: Anyway thank you for the information, at least now I understand my limits, I accept this answer as the best solution.

Comment: Ah! You can certainly look into using a FileSystemObject since it will return all that information.

Comment: Yeah, I know it does, I use it in other parts of my scrip, but it would be overcomplicated to implement. To create the userform, display all the information needed, etc. If I will have more time to play with it, at least I will have the search engine that you gave me. So this is a good start, I just taught that there would be an easier workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Why not avoid using shell all together and use something like this,

```
        Dim myFolder As String
        Dim myFile As String
        Dim wb as Workbook
        Dim i As Long, tempLimit As Long
        Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Title = "Select Folder Containing Excel Files"
        myFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .Show
            If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
                myFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
            End If
        End With
        myFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.xls*")
        Do While myFile <> ""
            Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(myFolder & "\" & myFile)
            ...
        Loop
```

Comment: I would like to avoid using shell, but I can't find a way to achieve the same result with any other method